# At the beginning of The Princess Bride, what game is being played?

Tags: game-identification

At the beginning of the 1987 film *The Princess Bride*, the grandson is playing a baseball game. Does anyone know what game it is?

(It's possible that this is a fake game that was mocked up just for this shot, but I'm naïvely guessing that that would have been a huge pain)

The movie opens with this shot:
[image]

And switches to this shot:
[image]

After that, his mother enters, and it cuts away from the game.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is the game [Hardball!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HardBall!) published by Accolade in 1985.